# tkinter After not running at correct speed

Tags: python, list, timer, tkinter

When using the following line:

```
self.window.after(transList[i_ref].tTimer, self.Enter)
```

with tTimer set to 100, after actually runs at approximately 239ms.

is this due to storing class values in a list type variable?

Class:

```
class TransMsg(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.canID   = ""
        self.msgType = ""
        self.canType = ""
        self.tData0  = ""
        self.tData1  = ""
        self.tData2  = ""
        self.tData3  = ""
        self.tData4  = ""
        self.tData5  = ""
        self.tData6  = ""
        self.tData7  = ""

        self.timer   = 0
        self.DLC     = 0
```

Instance creation:

```
def addToList(self,event):

        global transList

        ref = len(transList)
        t = TransMsg()

        t.canID = self.IDbox.get()
        t.DLC = self.DLCBox.get()
        t.canType = "s"
        t.msgType = "m"
        t.tData0 = self.tData0Box.get()
        t.tData1 = self.tData1Box.get()
        t.tData2 = self.tData2Box.get()
        t.tData3 = self.tData3Box.get()
        t.tData4 = self.tData4Box.get()
        t.tData5 = self.tData5Box.get()
        t.tData6 = self.tData6Box.get()
        t.tData7 = self.tData7Box.get()
        t.tTimer = self.tTimerBox.get()

        transList.append(t)

        self.Translist.insert("end","%s %d %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %d" %
                ( transList[ref].canID,
                 int(transList[ref].DLC),
                 transList[ref].tData0,
                 transList[ref].tData1,
                 transList[ref].tData2,
                 transList[ref].tData3,
                 transList[ref].tData4,
                 transList[ref].tData5,
                 transList[ref].tData6,
                 transList[ref].tData7,
                 int(transList[ref].tTimer)))
```

When using a Dictionary, there seems to be no deviation from the time set.

function with after:

```
def Enter(self):
        global running
        items = self.Translist.curselection()
        for i in items:
            i_ref = int(i)
            if(int(transList[i_ref].tTimer) <= 0):
                system('echo "%s %s 0x%s %d 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s" >/dev/pcan33' %
                    (transList[i_ref].msgType,
                    transList[i_ref].canType,
                    transList[i_ref].canID,
                    int(transList[i_ref].DLC),
                    transList[i_ref].tData0,
                    transList[i_ref].tData1,
                    transList[i_ref].tData2,
                    transList[i_ref].tData3,
                    transList[i_ref].tData4,
                    transList[i_ref].tData5,
                    transList[i_ref].tData6,
                    transList[i_ref].tData7))

            else:
                if running == 1:
                    running = 0
                    break

                system('echo "%s %s 0x%s %d 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s" >/dev/pcan33' %
                    (transList[i_ref].msgType,
                    transList[i_ref].canType,
                    transList[i_ref].canID,
                    int(transList[i_ref].DLC),
                    transList[i_ref].tData0,
                    transList[i_ref].tData1,
                    transList[i_ref].tData2,
                    transList[i_ref].tData3,
                    transList[i_ref].tData4,
                    transList[i_ref].tData5,
                    transList[i_ref].tData6,
                    transList[i_ref].tData7))
                self.window.after(transList[i_ref].tTimer, self.Enter)
```

Could some-one please clarify what could cause this or advise how I can debug it?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, `after` just ensures that at least X milliseconds pass before the function is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`after` does not guarantee that it will wait exactly as long as the time you specify, so it's not suitable for precise timing applications. From the [effbot documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method):

> This method registers a callback function that will be called after a given number of milliseconds. Tkinter only guarantees that the callback will not be called earlier than that; if the system is busy, the actual delay may be much longer.

Although exact precision is not possible, it may be possible to get closer to your desired time if you put the `after` call as high up in your function as possible, so it isn't further delayed by slow operations occurring between it and the start of the function. In your case, try moving it to just above the `system` call.

Comment: Is there an more precise function that I can use in place of `after`

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The problem with Tkinter (and every other general purpose UI library, I assume) is that the operating system is allowed to ignore your process for as long as it deems necessary. So any kind of "wait 100 ms" command can take a million seconds to execute, if the OS' attention is elsewhere. You would need some kind of high-precision timing library, which doesn't exist in Python's standard lib.